# angularjs print datafrom API

Tags: angularjs, json

Trying to print data from an API call to one of my views:

```
{{forecast.list.rain['3h']}}
```

Making the API call successfully and the data logs in the console.

```
var urlForecast = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + 
                  $routeParams.cityId + 
                  "&appid=d436c04d23a5a44329eb8255190a84be&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

var forecastCall = urlForecast;
var promise2 = $http.jsonp(forecastCall);

promise2.success(function(forecast) {
    $scope.forecast = forecast;
    console.log($scope.forecast);
});
```

Not printing anything, cant see whats wrong.

Comment: Can you please update the response `$scope.forecast` in question.

Comment: update $scope.forecast?

Comment: I want to see the response you getting in `$scope.forecast` object

Comment: from the console?

Comment: Yes in the console.

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "load"}

Comment: Can you please expand the whole `data` object.

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "load"}
config
:
Object
data
:
Object
city
:
Object
coord
:
Object
country
:
"US"
id
:
5368361
name
:
"Los Angeles"
population
:
0
sys
:
Object
population
:
0
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
cnt
:
37
cod
:
"200"
list
:
Array[37]
message
:
0.0544
__proto__
:
Object
headers
:
(d)
status
:
200
statusText
:
"load"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126294/discussion-between-rohit-jindal-and-znowman).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.then` instead of `.success`, because if there's an error, `.success` method is not firing.

Comment: Not printing anything, can print data from other API calls made in the same way, its just this one for some reason.